# How to find the probability that exactly two of the selected objects are balls given that exactly one of them is yellow

Tags: probability

A box contains 20 objects: 2 yellow balls, 4 green balls, 6 yellow cubes, and 8 green cubes. Three objects are randomly selected from the box, one at a time and are not replaced. Event A and B are defined as follows:
Event A: exactly one of the objects selected is yellow
Event B: exactly two of the objects are balls

Find Probability of event A and event B happening, hence find the probability of event B happening given event A has happened?

I approached the question by multiplying P(A) and P(B) together to get the probability of event A AND event B happening. Next, to find the answer to the next question, I did (Probability of event A and event B happening)/(Probability of event A happening)

Is this correct, or must I draw a venn diagram to assist me with the question (or can I really draw a venn diagram for this question?)

Comment: Not correct. You assumed that $A$ and $B$ are independent events. But are they?

Comment: Yes, I assumed. They might be not, so how else should I approach the question, with a venn diagram?

Comment: Can you first try writing down the cases which will lead to the intersection of the events $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Please bear with me as I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intersection of events $A$ and $B$ will lead to following cases,

- $1$ yellow cube and $2$ green balls.
- $1$ yellow ball, $1$ green ball and $1$ green cube.

Number of ways for case $1$ to happen is $\binom{6}{1}\binom{4}{2}$ and number of ways for case $2$ to happen is $\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{8}{1}$. Total number of ways in which $3$ random objects can be chosen is $\binom{20}{3}$.

So, $P(A \wedge B) = \frac{\binom{6}{1}\binom{4}{2} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{8}{1}}{\binom{20}{3}}$

Now, write the cases for event $A$ only and compute $P(A)$ in a similar way. And use $P(B|A) = \frac{P(A \wedge B)}{P(A)}$ to get your conditional probability.

Cases for event $A$ to happen are,

> $1$ yellow ball and $2$ green coloured objects.

and

> $1$ yellow cube and $2$ green coloured objects.

Finally,

> $P(A) = \frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{12}{2} + \binom{6}{1}\binom{12}{2}}{\binom{20}{3}}$

Comment: Thanks for the benevolent answer but, how did you list down the intersections of events A and B, that's where I'm a bit lost

Comment: Exactly one object is yellow and exactly two objects are balls. There is no other way/case the $3$ randomly selected objects will satisfy these conditions.

Comment: For the second case, shouldn't the "1 cube of any color" be "1 green cube"? If you selected a yellow cube given that you selected a yellow ball, then you would have two yellow objects, which would contradict event A, no?

Comment: I didn't see your name. Sorry for my last comment. Yes I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

**An attempt to describe the intersection of two events**

So thinking about intersections of two events $A$ and $B$ means thinking that these two events occur simultaneously. They are not mutually exclusive (independent) events, because these events can clearly occur at the same time. In a way, you could think about them in terms of a venn diagram, but you don't need, nor would I recommend, using one. Rather, it is better to ask, "What does it *mean* for objects to be in the intersection of two events in a venn diagram?" These objects belong to the intersection, because these objects satisfy both properties described by the events (sets) $A$ and $B$. Think of $A$ and $B$ being two pieces of information such that their intersection $A \cap B$ describes something using both of these characteristics.

**An example of independent events**

An example of two independent events using this example with balls and cubes would be letting $A$ denote the event, "All three objects selected are balls," and $B$ is the event, "Exactly one of the objects selected is a cube." Then if we are selecting three out of the twenty balls, the event $A \cap B$ says that the three objects chosen are three balls and one cube. That's nonsense, because we are only selecting three objects; you cannot tell me that I have selected three balls while also selecting a cube, so these events are mutually exclusive.

**An attempt to enumerate the combinations of this example**

First, we know that we have three objects, let's represent it with the string *** of three asterisks.

The event $A \cap B$ means out of three of the selected objects, two of them are balls and one of them is yellow.

Let b represent a ball. Then the string becomes bb*. Note that the order in which the b's occur is irrelevant; therefore, the string bb* is the same as *bb.

Now what do we do with the third asterisk? Can it be another b? Well, no, because we require exactly two balls. Therefore the third * must be a cube c, so our string becomes bbc.

Now we need to think about colors.

We know that in the string bbc there is only one yellow object. That means the other two must be green. So, what are the possibilities?

1. I could have two green balls and one yellow cube.
2. I could have one yellow ball, one green ball and one green cube.

And those are the only possibilities!